# check page extension in localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, localhost

If there is a PHP file on the server like mypage.php and when I request it from localhost like:

```
http://localhost/mypage
```

back with mypage.php with no problem but when request it on the live server came with 404 error!

I ask how to make the localhost act like live server and must enter the full name of the file with its extension so http://localhost/mypage came with 404 error

And I want to edit httpd.conf

Comment: do you mean you want to remove file extension..?

Comment: I ask to make the localhost act like live server and must enter the fullname of the file with its extension so http://localhost/mypage came with 404 error

Comment: read about `.htaccess` and mod-rewrite;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the [Multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#options)-option is set on localhost. If it does, remove it and restart the server.